# Drag 1 node: move his children too

Tags: sigma.js

I have a tree in `sigmajs`.  If I drag a parent node, I want to move the children nodes, too. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is doable with [Linkurious.js](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js), a project that provides high-level features to Sigma.js and is free for open source projects.

- build a custom selector with [sigma.plugins.select](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/linkurious-version/plugins/sigma.plugins.select)
- use [sigma.plugins.dragNodes](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/linkurious-version/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes) to drag the selected nodes

*Disclaimer:* I work at Linkurious SAS.

Comment: is it possible to select group of nodes dynamically using select plugin? let's say i have community graph and if i choose fb then all nodes which comes under fb community should be got selected.